# Git Pull without typing private key password

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell, cron

I'm going to setup a cronjob for git pull changes on my test webserver. But my private key has a password, How could i pass it as argument?

```
git pull something mypassword
```

I'm willing to use it on a cronjob and I don't want to leave private key without password.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set up http:// access to your repo?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to leave the private key without a password but you have no problems with storing the password in the cron job description? That seems a bit odd.

You might be able to do it with ssh-agent (not sure, but search for it), but quite frankly I find it a bit silly.

Comment: A rule of thumb for automated cronjob-style invocations is to use a separate, very tightly secured passwordless private key (i.e. using a separate user with very curtailed privileges).

Answer (score 1):

No problem. `keychain` is what you need. You should be able to find it in your distro. There is a [guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) for Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is read-only access. To do this via SSH:

1. **Create a user** at the remote server which has **read-only** access to the repository path.
2. **Log in** with this user via SSH and **verify** that you're able to read files (`less /path/to/repo/.git/config`) but not write (`touch /path/to/repo/.git/config` should fail).
3. Create an SSH key **without a password** in a path readable by `cron`.
4. Enable passwordless login with `ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/passwordless/id.pub cron-user@server.example.com`
5. Add `eval $(ssh-agent); ssh-add /path/to/passwordless/id;` at the beginning of the script listed in `crontab`.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an expect script to provide the password when needed. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set password ssh-key-password

spawn git pull
expect "Enter passphrase*:" {send "$password\r"}
```

You may need to include

```
expect eof
```

at the end of the script